Schedule Optimization Problem don't know a better way to present the solution - Python / Gekko
So my music school runs a festival for all student bands to play together.
Since there are some family members across diferent bands, I'm trying to create a solution to optimize the schedule of the bands - trying to minimize sum of time between bands that have relatives. Now I think I've found a solution. Don't know if it's the best but it looks like it's working. Now I'm trying to find a better way to present the solution. This "x" matrix is huge and maybe it would be better to extract only the "1"s and make a schedule table with the slots and what band is in a cronological order. But I don't know where to start. Hoping someone can point the direction.
Relevant infos:

English is not my first language;
I'm not a programmer, and everything I did at the code bellow was what I was able to learn about python last 2 days.

I'm using the code bellow. Feel free to criticize and make any suggestions. Thanks!
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()

#variables and constrains
n = 20 #n of bands
s = 37 #n of slots to play
t = 25 #time in minutes one band spend on the stage

x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,s),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True) #matrix of all bands(rows) x slots (columns)
for j in range(s):
        m.Equation(m.sum([x[i,j] for i in range(n)])<=1) #since this is the decision i made it binary and sum=1 to 1 band only ocuppie one slot
for i in range(n):
        m.Equation(m.sum([x[i,j] for j in range(s)])==1) #since this is the decision i made it binary and sum=1 to 1 band only ocuppie one slot
       
z = [k for k in range(1,s+1)] #array with slot index to use to calc time 
w = z*x*t #time the band will perform ;; used in objetive function


#objective
#in this exemple the band (1,4) and the band (1,5) have a relationship, and so do (3,2) and (1,15), so the objetive function bellow will try to minimize the sum of the time between bands that have relationship 
y = m.abs2(w.item(1, 4)-w.item(1, 5))+ m.abs2(w.item(3, 2)-w.item(1, 15)) 
m.Minimize(y)


#solver
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()



#print(w.item((1, 4)))
print('y')
print(y)
print('x')
print(x)



Wouldn't mind either if you'd mark my answer as correct .

You need to extract the band and slot numbers for each 1 in the matrix and sort the schedule by slot number:
schedule = [(i+1, j+1) for i in range(n) for j in range(s) if x[i,j][0] == 1]
schedule.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for band, slot in schedule:
    print(f"Band {band} is scheduled to play in slot {slot}")


Perfect! Just let me understand better ('couse I'm learning python by myself and now I'm thinking maybe I should look for some course or something like that...) but anyway, what "key = lambda" is doing in this function?
And if it's not abusing your good will to help, is there any way I can correlate one new array with the band's names to this final visualisation?

Lambda creates an "anonymous" function. Used when you need a small function for a short period of time and don't want to define with using "def". Usually seen when working with functions that sort or ordere data. As for the second question I'd recommend writing another question and @me.

Thank you. I did as you suggested, and created a new question. I have no idea if I did it correctly (to mark you on my new question). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78486029/schedule-optimization-problem-trying-to-present-the-solution-in-a-better-way-p
